# Not able to access a variable

Tags: javascript, protractor

The variable i am using becomes **undefined** after a certain point. Can someone help me in understanding what is happening.

The below code is a protractor code.

```
this.searchBy = element(by.model('searchCompanyComponent.searchByValue'));

this.clickTheProvidedValueInSearchByDropdown = function (selectedItem) {
    var x = this.searchBy;
    this.searchBy.all(by.tagName('option')).filter(function (elem, index) {
        return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
            return text.toUpperCase().replace(/ |-/g, '') === selectedItem.toUpperCase().replace(/ |-/g, '');
        });
    }).getText().then(function (text) {
        console.info(x); // 1
        console.log(this.searchBy); // 2            
    });


};
 console.log(this.searchBy); //3
```

The console log at 1 and 3 shows the locator object, but console log at 2 shows as undefined.

What is the reason behind this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` can mean a lot of different things depending on the context in which you are referencing it.

When you are saying  `console.log(this.searchBy); // 2` you are in the context of the anonymous function you passed to `getText`, which has no `searchBy` property. You will either need to `bind` this function to the context of your page object or use the stored reference to `searchBy` in `x`

It may be helpful to review [this mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)